# how to find actual IP address when HAProxy is used with Grpc for load balancing?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, haproxy, grpc

We are using Grpc (C# library) with protobuf to perform internal RPC in a local network. I am using HAProxy to perform Roundrobin balancing so as to distribute the load to one of the 2 servers. Since I am creating a `Singleton` Channel and using the same to perform all RPC calls, the load balancing is not happening. When I give the proxy IP as a serverlist while creating the GRPC `Channel`, the IP does not resolve to actual physical IP rather it shows only the proxy IP in the `ResolvedTarget` field of Channel object. My question is how can I have `Singleton` objects for each of the Servers and still use HAproxy to do load balancing? Or it is not possible to use HAProxy and at the same time use channel as a Singleton object?

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing any load balancing because whenever possible, gRPC uses a single persistent TCP connection to send requests to the server. So, when you open a connection to the HAProxy, it "load balances" that single connection to one of the servers. Then that connection stays open for as long as your application runs, so the load balancing functionality is never enganged again.

You see the connected IP address as the proxy's IP address because you are actually connected to the proxy. HAProxy forwards your packets to the backend server.

This means that with or without singleton Channels, HAProxy will not send multiple gRPC requests from a single client to different servers. However, HAProxy is still useful with gRPC, because it will still load balance connections from *different* clients to different backends.

Comment: _However, HAProxy is still useful with gRPC, because it will still load balance connections from different clients to different backends._. I had the same assumption  but it did not happen this way when I created the singleton channel. All requests from all clients went  to only one server. I know it coz I was logging the channel requests to graylog.